# How to get facebook session key with facebook-java-api

Tags: facebook, facebook-java-api

How do I get the session key with the facebook-java-api ?#
What I did so far is this :

After I authorised my app to acces my facebook account I do get 
redirected to the right redirect url in my app and there I do

```
     FacebookJsonRestClient facebookClient = new FacebookJsonRestClient ('key', 'secaret')
     String token =  facebookClient.auth_createToken()
```

With the returned token I try to get the session key

```
def sessKey = facebookClient.auth_getSession(token)
```

But the ends up in :

errors.GrailsExceptionResolver JSONObject["session_key"] not found.
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["session_key"] not found.
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:498)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:669)
    at com.google.code.facebookapi.ExtensibleClient.auth_getSession(ExtensibleClient.java:288)
    at com.google.code.facebookapi.ExtensibleClient.auth_getSession(ExtensibleClient.java:274)

What am I missing here ? The documentation is no help at all.
Javadocs also is no help at all. 
Is someone out there who can recommend me a java library to use for facebook access ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That library is very outdated. I would recommend switching to [RestFB](http://restfb.com/). If you go to their site they have tons of examples.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below line of code:

```
string Session_Key=Request.QueryString.Get("fb_sig_session_key").ToString();
```